# SwiftUI: How to display a PDF file and then change it to a different file?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, swiftui

I have this code that displays a PDF, and the PDF loads fine. However, I've added a toolbar button to change the PDF to a different file, but it doesn't work. I don't get any error messages, but the View is not updated to show the new file.

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
    }
}

struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file1", withExtension: "pdf")!
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            PDFKitView(url: documentURL)
            .toolbar {
                Button("Change PDF") {
                    documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file2", withExtension: "pdf")!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to add something to `updateUIView` that loads a different file when the URL changes. Or (much more hacky), you can add a `.id()` to the `PDFKitView` that is the URL to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind elaborating on how to add the .id()?

Comment: Add `.id(documentURL` to the `PDFKitView(...)` call site

Comment: I did not downvote it. Please keep in mind that using `id` is likely *not* the best solution here. Correctly using `updateUIView` would be better

Comment: How should I update using updateUIView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the necessary code in `updateUIView` function. You can simplify the code even more:

```
struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        PDFView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        uiView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
    }
}
```